# How to replace a float value with NaN in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, replace, nan

I'm aware about the replace function in pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

But I've done this simple test and it is not working as expected when I try to replace a float value:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
print(df.head(n=1))

      A         B        C         D
0  1.437202  1.919894 -1.40674 -0.316737

df = df.replace(1.437202, np.nan)
print(df.head(n=1))

      A         B        C         D
0  1.437202  1.919894 -1.40674 -0.316737
```

As you see the [[0],[0]] has no change...any idea about what this could be due to?

Answer (score 6):

Problem is float precision, so use function [`numpy.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
print(df.head(n=1))
          A         B         C         D
0 -1.085631  0.997345  0.282978 -1.506295

df = df.mask(np.isclose(df.values, 0.997345))
```

Or use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
arr = np.where(np.isclose(df.values, 0.997345), np.nan, df.values)
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

---

```
print(df.head(n=1))
          A   B         C         D
0 -1.085631 NaN  0.282978 -1.506295
```

EDIT: You can also get only numeric columns by [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) for filtering by subset with `[]`:

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50, 4), columns=list('ABCD')).assign(E='a')

cols = df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns
df[cols] = df[cols].mask(np.isclose(df[cols].values, 0.997345))
print(df.head(n=1))
          A   B         C         D  E
0 -1.085631 NaN  0.282978 -1.506295  a
```

Comment: Good options indeed, but they both fail if the column's datatypes are not all numeric. If I set a random value with a string `df.iloc[[0], [0]] = 'random_string'` and then I try to apply both methods over the whole dataset, they return an error `TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

Comment: Maybe I should have explained that before. The example I gave was only with numeric values, but I'm looking for a method that should work with features of any type'

Comment: @ralvarez - Added general solution - filtering only numeric columns and apply solution

Answer (score 0):

Just a another trick for specific indices :

```
>>> print(df.head(n=1))
          A         B         C         D
0 -0.042839  1.701118  0.064779  1.513046

>>> df['A'][0] = np.nan

>>> print(df.head(n=1))
    A         B         C         D
0 NaN  1.701118  0.064779  1.513046
```